# firebase cloud messging to multiple users with C# server

Tags: c#, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send FCM notifications to multiple phones at once with my c# server.  I can send messages to one phone at a time with the following code,

```
 try
        {
            var applicationID = "xAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6g9vOeEmw1njaivVfIx";
            var senderId = "x7xxxxxxxxxxx5x";
            string deviceId = pushToken;
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var msg2send = new
            {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = msg,
                    title = "My Car Wash App",
                    icon = "myicon"
                },
                data = new
                {
                    priority = 10,
                    notice = msg
                }
            };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(msg2send);

         Response.Write(json);

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        string sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                        Response.Write(sResponseFromServer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

that works perfectly but I loop through my tokens and call that method over and over making hundreds of requests and that's not good

I am trying to send a multi cast message as I can just pass in an array with all the tokens but I keep on getting bad request

```
var msg2send = new
            {
                registration_ids = "[id1, id2]",
                notification = new
                {
                    body = msg,
                    title = "My Car Wash App",
                    icon = "myicon"
                },
                data = new
                {
                    priority = 10,
                    notice = msg
                }
            };
```

I am positive that registration_ids is a correct array with valid tokens when I send my request.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help or suggestions would really be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also post the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Firebase Device Group Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group), you can [create a device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-the-app-server) and register all the device tokens in it, then [send downstream messages to client apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#sending_downstream_messages_to_device_groups) using the JSON payload below.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
   "to": "aUniqueKey",
   "data": {
      "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Message!",
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It has been quite long and I think this is the correct answer after doing a lot of google searching. I will put it here for other developers get pass through this bug.

The problem is **registration_ids = "[id1, id2]"**, // the registration_ids **needs the string array** but you assigned it with a string. That's why a lot of developers are getting the bad request but dont know why.

**Solution:** Try to create an array outside var msg2send = new {...}. I tested it and its working 100%

```
string[] deviceIds = new string[] {"id1","id2","id3"};
var msg2send = new
            {
                registration_ids = deviceIds,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = msg,
                    title = "My Car Wash App",
                    icon = "myicon"
                },
                data = new
                {
                    priority = 10,
                    notice = msg
                }
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for this replay, it helped me a lot!